# Hide stop button from job

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I created a job that is triggered when an environment is stopped:

```
deploy:test:
  stage: deploy:test
  environment:
    name: test
    on_stop: stop:test


stop:test:
  stage: stop:test
  environment: 
    name: test
    action: stop
  when: manual
  script:
    ...
```

and this configuration created this job in the pipeline

[image]

How can I remove or hide the STOP button from the job component?

I want the job to be triggered only when I press STOP on the environment from the Operate > Environments menu and not from the pipeline.

I attempted to add a rule in the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file, but it hid the entire component rather than just the button. I want a developer to be able to see the status of the triggered job but not be able to trigger it from there.

I tried to remove `action: stop` but Gitlab requires it

Answer (score 1):

You cannot hide the job/stop button in the pipeline view when using the `on_stop:` feature. Developers that have the ability to stop the environment from the environments page can also run the manual job -- both actions are just two ways of doing the exact same thing.